# JQuery combining variable names

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say I have variables like this:

```
localStorage.var1a = 0;
localStorage.varnum = 1000;
```

And a code like this:

```
for(x = 1; x <localStorage.varnum;x++){
  if(localStorage.var.x.a > 0){
     localStorage.var.x.a  = Number(localStorage.var.x.a)
  }else{
     localStorage.var.x.a = 0;
  }
}
```

My problem is, I have no idea how to combine x and localStorage.var * a;

Comment: *"I have no idea how to combine x and localStorage.var * a"* with string concatenation. Then you can use bracket notation to access the property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if(localStorage["var"+x+"a"] > 0){
     localStorage["var"+x+"a"]  = Number(localStorage["var"+x+"a"]);
  }else{
    localStorage["var"+x+"a"]= 0;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: by eval value of "localStorage.var"+x+"a" come

Comment: Why don't you use `localStorage["var"+x+"a"]` as well?